# "Couldn't load font" LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, fonts

yesterday I started working om making custom sized fonts to my game, in game, using `FreeTypeFaceGenerator`, and yesterday it worked fine, except an exception I was going to handle today. When I loaded it up today, and tried to run it, it keeps crashing in the part where I create the FTFGen object, I have no idea how to fix this.
How do I fix this, where do I even begin? I changed to font file and it gives me the same error it did yesterday, but I don't want the other file (Vivaldi), I need the one I'm testing (Viner Hand ITC).
How do I fix this? I'm using .TTF files, not making a bitmapfont file.

I don't want to provide my own source code, but I'll post the same way, just change a couple of things:
(I followed a guide located [here](http://ilearnsomethings.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/libgdx-generate-bitmap-fonts-for-any.html) )
The method recieves three parameters, A `FileHandle` of the font file, a `String` of the font name, and a `float` array with all the sizes which will then turn to size of the font using
  `(int)(size*Gdx.graphics.getDensity())`
This is the code:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator ftfGen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(handle);
    for (float x : size) {
        PixmapPacker packer = new PixmapPacker(512, 512, Format.RGBA8888,
                2, false);
        FreeTypeBitmapFontData fontData = ftfGen.generateData(
                (int) (x * Gdx.graphics.getDensity()),
                FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS, false, packer);
        Array<Page> pages = packer.getPages();
        TextureRegion[] textureRegions = new TextureRegion[pages.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size; i++) {
            Page p = pages.get(i);
            Texture texture = new Texture(new PixmapTextureData(
                    p.getPixmap(), p.getPixmap().getFormat(), false, false,
                    true)) {
                @Override
                public void dispose() {
                    super.dispose();
                    getTextureData().consumePixmap().dispose();
                }
            };
            texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest,
                    Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
            textureRegions[i] = new TextureRegion(texture);
            BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(fontData, textureRegions,
                    false);
            FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("Data\\VINERITC.TTF");
            FileHandle pixmapDir = Gdx.files.local("Data\\VINERITC");
            BitmapFontWriter.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Text);
            String[] pageRefs = BitmapFontWriter.writePixmaps(
                    packer.getPages(), pixmapDir, fontName);
            for (int j = 0; j < pageRefs.length; j++) {
                pageRefs[j] = fontName + "_" + pageRefs[j];
            }
            BitmapFontWriter.writeFont(
                    font.getData(),
                    pageRefs,
                    file,
                    new FontInfo(fontName, (int) (x * Gdx.graphics
                            .getDensity())), 1, 1);
            packer.dispose();
        }

    }
```

The error I am receiving is in this line of code: 
 `FreeTypeFontGenerator ftfGen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(handle);`

 Upon digging around in the code of LibGDX I found out that it is caused by this method, which uses a native method:

```
    public static Face newMemoryFace(Library library, byte[] data, int dataSize, int faceIndex) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.newUnsafeByteBuffer(data.length);
    BufferUtils.copy(data, 0, buffer, data.length);
    long address = newMemoryFace(library.address, buffer, dataSize, faceIndex);
    if(address == 0) {
        BufferUtils.disposeUnsafeByteBuffer(buffer);
        throw new GdxRuntimeException("Couldn't load font");
    }
    else {
        library.fontData.put(address, buffer);
        return new Face(address, library);
    }
}

private static native long newMemoryFace(long library, ByteBuffer data, int dataSize, int faceIndex);
```

This part gives out the error:

```
long address = newMemoryFace(library.address, buffer, dataSize, faceIndex);
        if(address == 0) {
            BufferUtils.disposeUnsafeByteBuffer(buffer);
            throw new GdxRuntimeException("Couldn't load font");
        }
```

The `newMemoryFace` is a native method.

**I FOUND THE PROBLEM!**
This line is the problem:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("Data\\VINERITC.TTF");
```

This line caused a creation of a new TTF file, and thus cause a problem with the loading system, make sure if you use this to write  `.fnt`  and not TTF.

Comment: If you're using version control, why not just roll back your change?

Comment: I'm not using version control, but it's the exact same code from last night the only thing I change was full screen so I could bugfix the problem which when using a different font creates the exception I was going to fix. I changed it back but it's still the same `Couldn't load font` exception...

Comment: Please begin by providing us current source code examples that we may look over as a starting point.

Comment: Added source code.

Comment: Please use version control. You'll save yourself hours of headaches. Git and Mercurial both work without a central server and allow local check-ins.

Comment: Alright I will, but again, I stress that there were **no changes** to the code except from canceling full screen.

Comment: I still can't fix it, what can I do? I tried replacing the font, with the same one but another copy, but it won't work..

Comment: Please post an answer to your own question so other people who run into this know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who had run into this problem, it originates from the creation (at least for me) of another TTF file in the local directory (I.e. "myGDXGame-desktop"), and this causes a problem with the loading of the font. Make sure that  this line, that is the save directory for the `.fnt` file, is not saving as `.TTF`
This was what's needed to be made:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("Data\\VINERITC.TTF");
```

Changed to this:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("Data\\VINERITC.fnt");
```